# Deserialization Json to C# using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have the following JSON that I need to parse :

```
{
    "code": 200, 
    "status": "OK", 
    "response": {
        "course_accessJSON": null, 
        "in_progress": 1, 
        "completed": 0, 
        "passed": 0, 
        "location": "http://*************************************", 
        "subscription": {
            "started": 1465834293, 
            "expired": 1473869493, 
            "payment": "account"
        }, 
        "is_expired": false, 
        "course_progress": {
            "CMP1044": {
                "course_name_en": "Java Programming", 
                "no_of_lessons": 30, 
                "viewed": 1, 
                "viewed_start": 1465834789, 
                "viewed_end": null, 
                "cert_attemptsCSV": null, 
                "cert_resetsCSV": null, 
                "cert_serial": null, 
                "high_score": null, 
                "location": "http://***************************"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have managed to get all the elements out except the value in the course_progress item using the following:

```
SampleResourse obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleResourse>(s);            
Response.Write(obj.Response.CourseProgress.CMP1044.CourseNameEn.ToString());
```

```
class SampleResourse
{
  [JsonProperty("code")]
  public int respcode { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("status")]
  public string respStatus { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("response")]
  public Response2 Response { get; set; }
}

class Response2
{
  [JsonProperty("in_progress")]
  public int InProgress { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("completed")]
  public int Completed { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("passed")]
  public int Passed { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("course_progress")]
  public CourseProgress CourseProgress { get; set; }

}

class CourseProgress
{

  [JsonProperty("CMP1044")]
  public CMP10442 CMP1044 { get; set; }
}

class CMP10442
{
  [JsonProperty("course_name_en")]
  public string CourseNameEn { get; set; }
}
```

I need the elements course_name_en, no_of_lessons,viewed however there will be multiple properties similar to `"CMP1044"`.  Each "CMP" property will have a unique number.  I want to list progress on each.

Answer (score 3):

Simply change the following :

```
class Response2
{
    [JsonProperty("in_progress")]
    public int InProgress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("completed")]
    public int Completed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("passed")]
    public int Passed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("course_progress")]
    public Dictionary<string, CourseProgress> CourseProgress { get; set; }
}
class CourseProgress
{
    [JsonProperty("course_name_en")]
    public string CourseNameEn { get; set; }
}
```

To list the course name along with the id, you can do this:

```
var resource = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleResourse>(json);
foreach (var kvp in resource.Response.CourseProgress)
{
    Response.Write(kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value.CourseNameEn + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: ive done that how would i get the elements in the courseProgress class so for each key in course_progress print the course_name_en

Comment: @SimonWarne if this worked, do Accept the Answer so OP gets credit. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/245495